# Installation help for Apache web server

Tags: dell

I Can download the package form synaptic package manager. When i select a package to download then it says that-

> please select a disk labeled
>   Ubuntu 13.10_saucy salamander_-Release amd64(20131016.1)
>   in drive/media/cdrom/

What is it and how to resolve it?
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to install it from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

or install it from software center

Answer (score 1):

Open your Ubuntu Software Center.

Go to Edit --> Software sources

[image]

Remove the check beside cdrom in the installable from CD-ROM/DVD menu

Now you should use synaptic normally.